# Docking WPF Window on single/multiple monitors

Tags: c#, wpf

So in my tool I've written a function which docks my wpf window to the right side or left side of the screen. It currently supports multiple monitors and takes into account what screen the app is within, before docking it.

However the function doesn't appear to work on single screen computers and I'm not entirely sure why that is. When i click the 'dock right' button it seems to dock the window off the screen. However the 'left' docking function works fine. Does anyone know why this would be? I have a 4k single monitor laptop.

**Dock Left Works Correctly - both single and multiple monitors**

```
System.Windows.Point cursorPos = PointToScreen(Mouse.GetPosition(this));
            int X = Convert.ToInt32(cursorPos.X);
            int Y = Convert.ToInt32(cursorPos.Y);

            System.Drawing.Point pt = new System.Drawing.Point(X, Y);
            Screen screen = Screen.FromPoint(pt);

            //this.Left = screen.WorkingArea.Left;
            this.Left = screen.Bounds.Left;
```

**Dock Right / BROKEN - only works on multiple monitors**

```
System.Windows.Point cursorPos = PointToScreen(Mouse.GetPosition(this));
            int X = Convert.ToInt32(cursorPos.X);
            int Y = Convert.ToInt32(cursorPos.Y);

            System.Drawing.Point pt = new System.Drawing.Point(X, Y);
            Screen screen = Screen.FromPoint(pt);

            this.Left = screen.Bounds.Right - this.Width;
```